# Did Voyager "shave off" more years than were necessary?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, continuity

Every *n* episodes of *ST:VOY*, we get to watch as the titular ship gets "years" taken off its journey through some benevolent being, or one-time-use technology.  In the beginning it was stated that they were something like 75 years away from the Alpha Quadrant, did the cumulative time they receive in "freebies" exceed this value?

Question brought about watching S05E15, *Dark Frontiers (pt 1)*, when Torres states that

> If I could equip our engines with even one [Borg trans-warp] coil, we could shave about 20 years off this trip.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As you've noted, there is indeed a slight discrepancy here. The total distance 'shaved' actually *exceeds* the straight-line distance, however we know that they *also* spent several years in normal space traveling at warp speeds.

- Voy: The Gift - "**9500 light years**" (courtesy of Kes)
- Voy: Night - "**2 years**" (e.g. 2000+ light years - via the The Malon vortex)
- Voy: Dark Frontier - "**20,300 light years**" (using a transwarp coil)
- Voy: Hope and Fear + Voy: Timeless - "**300 lights years + 10000 light years**" respectively (using a quantum slipstream).
- Voy: The Voyager Conspiracy - **"1000 light years"** (using a quantum catapult)
- Voy: Counterpoint - Unspecified, but substantial (via a wormhole)
- Voy: Dragon's Teeth - "**200 light years**" (via a Vauudwar subspace corridor)
- Voy: Q2 "**A few years**" (e.g. 2000+ light years - courtesy of Q)
- Voy: Endgame: Part 2 - "**30000 light years**" (via a transwarp corridor)

Of their total journey distance at the start (e.g. 75,000 light years) around 75,300 light years was *explicitly* stated to have been 'shaved'.

---

So how do we account for this?

- **Rounding.** The crew may have rounded up to the nearest few hundred light years when jumping really big distances. 20,000 could easily mean 19,751
- **Meandering.** As evidenced by the crew continually encountering the Kazon in the early seasons, it would appear that their early episodes involved traveling in circles collecting supplies
- **Not actually a straight line.** It would be remarkable if the various wormholes and corridors headed in an arrow-straight line toward the Alpha Quadrant. The time taken to head back onto their original course could easily add up to a few years travel.

Comment: I recall another question in which an answer showed they actually entered the Beta Quadrant before returning to the Alpha. This would substantiate that they didn't travel in such a straight line.

Comment: @MarkEdward - https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f3/65/7f/f3657fa278428e8160df8451a3397048.jpg I think your map-reading skills need a little work :-)

Comment: Well dang. I must've completely fabricated that memory... But thanks for the graphic!

Comment: Excellent answer.  I also found this last night while doing research of my own, and then slept and forgot about it. But, it's interesting if anyone wants a good breakdown (though it ends at season 4, which is too bad): http://www.stdimension.org/int/Cartography/Voyager.htm

Comment: @n_b - The discrepancy in distance is probably because Paris took a straight-line distance without taking into account any galactic phenomena. Like taking a distance calcuiation from London to Paris but then realising that you need to detour to Dover

Comment: In terms of the time-saver in Q2; we don't know that they ever were able to take advantage of that. Q didn't just send them closer; he gave them info that would shave a few years off their journey. This could have been info about a worm hole they could use in a couple years. Or something to improve their engines so that over the course of 50 years they would save a couple.

Comment: @GendoIkari - Sure, but this is Q we're talking about. He's hardly likely to have given them a nothingburger. It's gotta be wormholes and flectures that are basically risk free

Comment: @Valorum Sure, but I'm saying that we don't know when that time saving would have occurred during their journey. Q could have snapped his fingers and sent them a few years closer to home; but instead he provided some info that would shave a few years off of their journey.  It's quite possible that the info wouldn't be useful for a couple more months; etc.